# How do I get a list with only the objects of the group(s) using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an objects table with columns and widths.

| column (int) | width (double) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| 0 | 105 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 |

I only need the group objects title where the width values are 100.
In the example, this would be the group title with column 1. A list with two titles.

```cs
var result = title.GroupBy(c => c.Column).?
```

Comment: `.Where(c => c.Width == 100).GroupBy(c => c.Column)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is the objects' title supposed to come from? Is that a separate field that you're not showing in your table? Is it always going to have the same value for rows with the same column value? If so, do you want it to show up multiple times, or only once? Please be a little more specific with your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = title
    .GroupBy(c => c.Column)
    .Where(g => g.All(t => t.Width == 100))
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Here is [Dotnet Fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7tGZwe)

Comment: Hello Cetin. That works. I have not seen the All function.

Answer (score 0):

> I only need the group objects title where all values width are equal to 100.

I understand the part "where all values widht are equal to 100.0". I don't understand the "I only need the group objects title". Your objects have only a 'Column' and a 'Width'. Or do you mean that your objects also have a 'Title'?

First some definitions, this makes it easier to talk about things.

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public int Column {get; set;}
    public double Width {get; set;}
}

IEnumerable<MyObject> myObjects = ... // the collection that you want to process
```

How about this:

```
var result = myObjects.Where(object => object.Width == 100.0)
                      .Select(object => object.Title);
```

In words: from your original sequence of MyObjects in variable myObjects, keep only those MyObjects that have a value for property Width that equals 100.0. From each of the remaining MyObjects select only the value of property Title.

Comment: No he doesn't want to get all having width = 100. He wants to get all column groups where members' width = 100. See my reply above.